# MongoDB values to Dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Basically I need to connect to MongoDB documents records and put into values into dict.

```
**MongoDB Values**
{ "_id" : "LAC1397", "code" : "MIS", "label" : "Marshall Islands", "mappingName" : "RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY" }
{ "_id" : "LAC1852", "code" : "COP", "label" : "Colombian peso", "mappingName" : "FOREIGN_CURRENCY_CODE"}
```

How do i map it to dict in the below fashion in python

```
**syntax :**
dict = {"mappingName|Code" : "Value" }

**Example :**
dict = { "RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY|MIS" : "Marshall Islands" , "FOREIGN_CURRENCY_CODE|COP" : "Colombian peso" , "COMM_LANG|ENG" : "English" }
```

```
**Python Code**

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.mongo
collection = db.masters
for post in collection.find():
```

Got stuck after this , not sure how to put into dict in the mentioned method

Comment: for each row of csv/ any DB, `your_dict[Mapping+'|'+Code] = Value`, key must be unique, else last value will be stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post` will be a `dict` with the values from mongo, so you can loop the records and append to a new dictionary. As the comments mention, any duplicates would be overridden by the last found value. If this might be an issue, consider a `sort()` on the `find()` function.

Sample code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one({ "_id" : "LAC1397", "code" : "MIS", "label" : "Marshall Islands", "mappingName" : "RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY" })
db.mycollection.insert_one({ "_id" : "LAC1852", "code" : "COP", "label" : "Colombian peso", "mappingName" : "FOREIGN_CURRENCY_CODE"})

mydict = {}
for post in db.mycollection.find():
    k = f"{post.get('mappingName')}|{post.get('code')}"
    mydict[k] = post.get('label')

print(mydict)
```

Gives:

```
{'RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY|MIS': 'Marshall Islands', 'FOREIGN_CURRENCY_CODE|COP': 'Colombian peso'}
```